# Unable to reassemble RAID10

Tags: linux, ubuntu, raid, data-recovery, software-raid

I'm not sure if this is the community to ask but I thought I would give it a shot:

Our server that runs a 14 drive RAID10 through a rocketraid 2470 controller refused to assemble. Our goal is not necessarily to recover a working RAID, but to get as much data back as possible.

Maybe as a consequence of the assembly failure, upon shutting down the server, it would get stuck in boot loops. So I'm currently running Ubuntu 16.04.1 from a USB. I've determined that 2 of 14  disks are faulty and have determined which ones they are. Using [this guide](https://raid.wiki.kernel.org/index.php/RAID_Recovery), I've determined which ones and attempted to reassemble without them. However, I keep running into an error:

```
ubuntu@ubuntu:~$ sudo mdadm --assemble --verbose --force /dev/md0 /dev/sdc1 /dev/sdd1 /dev/sde1 /dev/sdf1 /dev/sdg1 /dev/sdh1 /dev/sdi1 /dev/sdj1 /dev/sdk1 /dev/sdl1 /dev/sdm1 /dev/sdn1 /dev/sdo1 /dev/sdp1
mdadm: looking for devices for /dev/md0
mdadm: /dev/sdc1 is identified as a member of /dev/md0, slot 0.
mdadm: /dev/sdd1 is identified as a member of /dev/md0, slot 1.
mdadm: /dev/sde1 is identified as a member of /dev/md0, slot 2.
mdadm: /dev/sdf1 is identified as a member of /dev/md0, slot 3.
mdadm: /dev/sdg1 is identified as a member of /dev/md0, slot 4.
mdadm: /dev/sdh1 is identified as a member of /dev/md0, slot 5.
mdadm: /dev/sdi1 is identified as a member of /dev/md0, slot 6.
mdadm: /dev/sdj1 is identified as a member of /dev/md0, slot 7.
mdadm: /dev/sdk1 is identified as a member of /dev/md0, slot 8.
mdadm: /dev/sdl1 is identified as a member of /dev/md0, slot 9.
mdadm: /dev/sdm1 is identified as a member of /dev/md0, slot 10.
mdadm: /dev/sdn1 is identified as a member of /dev/md0, slot 11.
mdadm: /dev/sdo1 is identified as a member of /dev/md0, slot 12.
mdadm: /dev/sdp1 is identified as a member of /dev/md0, slot 13.
mdadm: added /dev/sdd1 to /dev/md0 as 1
mdadm: added /dev/sde1 to /dev/md0 as 2
mdadm: added /dev/sdf1 to /dev/md0 as 3
mdadm: added /dev/sdg1 to /dev/md0 as 4
mdadm: added /dev/sdh1 to /dev/md0 as 5
mdadm: added /dev/sdi1 to /dev/md0 as 6
mdadm: added /dev/sdj1 to /dev/md0 as 7
mdadm: added /dev/sdk1 to /dev/md0 as 8
mdadm: added /dev/sdl1 to /dev/md0 as 9
mdadm: added /dev/sdm1 to /dev/md0 as 10
mdadm: added /dev/sdn1 to /dev/md0 as 11 (possibly out of date)
mdadm: added /dev/sdo1 to /dev/md0 as 12 (possibly out of date)
mdadm: added /dev/sdp1 to /dev/md0 as 13 (possibly out of date)
mdadm: added /dev/sdc1 to /dev/md0 as 0
mdadm: /dev/md0 assembled from 11 drives - not enough to start the array.
```

Here is the output of a mdadm --examine call.

```
ubuntu@ubuntu:~$ sudo mdadm --examine /dev/sd[c-p]1 | egrep 'Events | /dev/sd'
   Events : 21988
   Events : 21988
   Events : 21988
   Events : 21988
   Events : 21988
   Events : 21988
   Events : 21988
   Events : 21988
   Events : 21988
   Events : 21988
   Events : 21988
   Events : 560
   Events : 21944
   Events : 560
```

So it's clear that the last three drives are out of date. It's possible that drives 11 and 13 were never really active, but since they were only partners in a raid 1, the array was unaffected until now. I'm hoping that if I can reassemble with the 12th drive, then I will be able to recover most of the data. Does anyone know what I can do about that? I've also tried without the "inactive" drives but it still isn't assembling drive 12. I know that I can try using --run, but I'm not sure if I'll lose data that way. I'm also hesitant to zero the superblock because I've always heard it was a last resort option.

Note that because I'm running this off a USB the usual `cat /proc/mdstat` doesn't return the array. Also, I don't know the structure of the array (if I did this would be a lot easier).

Thanks in advance for the help.

Answer (score 0):

If you're only interested in trying to recover the data, you should be able to assemble a degraded, somewhat corrupted array with

```
sudo mdadm --assemble --verbose --force /dev/md0 /dev/sdc1 /dev/sdd1 /dev/sde1 /dev/sdf1 /dev/sdg1 /dev/sdh1 /dev/sdi1 /dev/sdj1 /dev/sdk1 /dev/sdl1 /dev/sdm1 /dev/sdo1
```

Note the omission of the badly-out-of-date `/dev/sdn1` and `/dev/sdp1` drives. Place the array in read-only mode

```
sudo mdadm --readonly /dev/md0
```

and activate it

```
sudo mdadm --run /dev/md0
```

Now you can mount the filesystem and attempt to recover data.  Note that since the array is in read-only mode, you may need to pass mount options to suppress things such as journal replay or other initial writes.

Since `/dev/sdo1` is out of date and presumably paired with either `/dev/sdn1` or `/dev/sdp1`, you aren't going to be able to recover everything.  Hopefully, the array is still in good enough condition that you're able to mount it and recover some data.